# How to hide horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: aqua;height:1500px;width:260px;overflow: hidden;">
            some text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My screen resolution is 1920 X 1200 (width X height) , I have div whose height is 1500 px. Obviously this will overflow the screen and browser adds vertical scroll by default.

My requirement is make this vertical scroll disappear and anything that is overflown outside the window just clipped off. How to get this behavior with css styles?

I tried overflow:hidden on div it didn't work for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: aqua;height:1500px;width:260px;overflow: hidden;">
            some text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to hide the overflow of body, not the div

Comment: Thanks I didn't understand the behavior. I set width and height of div but when I want to remove the scroll why do I set it to body??

Comment: body is container of the div. for this reason you need to add the overflow:hidden to the body for instance.

Comment: Thanks Kevin makes sense :)

Comment: it's simple!!! the body is the parent for all the other element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the below snippet could help you.

```css
body{height:1200px; width:100%; overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: aqua;height:1500px;width:260px;">
            some text
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a page/object from overflowing by adding the overflow property.

overflow | **y/x axis** 
overflow-y | **y axis** 
overflow-x | **x axis**

followed up by hidden as a value

hidden - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please explain a little bit more about your solution. Providing just code is not enough, even if it's correct.

Comment: As far as I understood overflow: hidden must be applied to parent of the element that  is overflowing, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @karansys - No, it's rarely the parent, but it's a bit complicated. In your case, it's the viewport to which `overflow:hidden` must be applied. A setting of the overflow on the body happens to work here, because that setting is getting moved to apply to the viewport automatically.